# Publish Map in Redis

Tags: java, redis

Is there a java api to publish `Map<String, Object>` (not `Map<String, String>` or `Map<String, byte[]>` to Redis?

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely - Redis' PubSub messages are Strings/Byte streams. That, however, shouldn't stop you from serializing (e.g. with JSON) the object, sending it, receiving it and deserializing it back to an object.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible with [Redisson](https://redisson.org). It offers transparent connection and serialization handling.

It supports various of codecs like `Jackson JSON`, `Avro`, `Amazon Ion`, `Smile`, `CBOR`, `MsgPack`, `Kryo`, `FST`, `LZ4`, `Snappy` and `JDK Serialization`

Here is an example with binary Kryo codec usage:

```
Config config = new Config();
config.setCodec(new KryoCodec());

RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);
Map<String, Object> map = redisson.getMap("myMap");
map.put("123", new AnyObject());
AnyObject object = map.get("123");
```